# How to avoid scientific notation conversion in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hex, scientific-notation

I want to convert a hex number in excel to two 4 character hex values.
My approach is:
1. I am using `TEXT` function to convert hex number to 8-character hex.
2. Then, use `MID` function to extract first 4 characters and other 4 characters.

This approach works fine for most of the cases. However, I have come across a particular scenario, in which, it is failing.

For example,

[image]

My hex value is `62823E4`. I wanted it to convert to `062823E4`. However, internally excel is considering `E4` as `10^4` (scientific notation). Formula used is shown in pic above.

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `=Rept(0,8-Len(B2)) & B2`?

Answer (score 1):

The TEXT function operates on numbers, so it will interpret hex data as decimal numbers.

Take a look at [HEX2DEC](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HEX2DEC-function-8C8C3155-9F37-45A5-A3EE-EE5379EF106E) and [DEC2HEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dec2hex-function-6344ee8b-b6b5-4c6a-a672-f64666704619) functions. If you start with hex strings, you should first extract their values with HEX2DEC. Then, using DEC2HEX you can restore the hex string with the required number of digits.

```
A1='62823E4
A2=HEX2DEC(A1)
A3=DEX2HEX(A2;8)
A5=LEFT(A3;4)
A6=RIGHT(A3;4)
```